# How to quit SAP using python and win32

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, sap-gui

I am automating a process with SAP using python and win32com.client. At the end of the process I want to quit the SAP application. For doing that I do click on "Abmelden" (session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press()) and then appears a popup window to confirm the action (see image). My problem is that I can't find a way to proceed with the confirmation. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
```

Regards, ScriptMan